# Determine if a table has rows of data or not using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-promise

Hello: I have an Angular test that includes a table of data after a search. So, I need to test if data exists or not and then do something if it does. Please advise how I can do this. I am still learning how to use "a promise" to test true or false situations, plus gather data from a promise. So, please help with specifics on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
it('ensures there is a table loaded before moving on', function() {
  expect($('table').isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
});

it('conditionally test stuff', function() {
  $$('table tr').count().then(function countRows(count) {
    if (count > 0) {
      // data exists
    } else {
      // no data found
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Elgalu, when I try your method
expect($('table').isPresent()).toBeTruthy();

I believe I get a promise back but how can I look in to the promise to tell if I am getting anything of value? Using webstorm in debug mode, I get a list of the following:

results = function(){
* arguments = null
* caller = null
* length = 0
* name = ''

PROTOTYPE = Object
* constructor = function(){
 
}

}

Comment: Just do your thing in `// data exists`. Debugging promises is tricky and why do you need to debug such a simple code? Maybe you're trying to understand all this with debugging but believe me in this case you're better off without it.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing...Learning as I code (debug)! LOL
Ok, I will try your method and get back. Thanks!

Comment: ha! cool. You could try opening a separate question on debugging Protractor promises with WebStorm, i'm sure other folks have doing it already! (not me hehe)